# EditText equals, show activity?

Tags: android, string

I want to create an application, that can provide information about a herb if you type it's name to a editText field, how to do that?

I have a textfield, where you input let's say "rose" and then you press the start, and I want the program to give you the activity, where you can find everything about the rose.

This is what I have now, but the program is not really reacting to it.

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
if (edit.getText().toString().equals("Rose")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, roseinformation.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Maybe I should implent it to my button press? Something like .... : if edittext equals rose, and id is button, start roseinformation activity?

```
public void onClick(View v)  {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, roseinformation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem actually???

Comment: Yeah you need to move the code that checks the text into the function that handles the button press

Comment: Yes must implement button click listener

Comment: If you attach a listener to only one button you do not need to make a check on the ID of the view since you know for sure that it's been triggered by your button. Just redirect the user to the appropriate page based on the string you have in your input

Comment: I don't know how to implent it to my button press, to check, that editText is equals to "rose" and memorize this, and start a new activity, roseinformation activity. I want my program to ONLY start the roseinformation activity, if editText equals to rose. But if I let's say want an information about tulip, then program should check that also if it's equals to tulip and correct me to the tulip activity.

Comment: Unrelated (yet): You probably don't want to create an extra Activity class for each herb you know. The layout and data will most likely have similar structure, you're better off creating one `HerbActivity` and pass the herb name via an *Intent extra*. Then in `HerbActivity` you read the name from intent extras and display appropriate content.

Comment: How to do that Eugen? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: See a simple example of passing text between activities at [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). Search for "intent.putExtra" and "intent.getStringExtra".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people have said in the comments under your question, move the logic into the button press listener:

```
public void onClick(View v)  {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            if (edit.getText().toString().equals("Rose")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, roseinformation.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `Buttton` click listener and check `EditText` value on `Button` click :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (edit.getText().toString().equals("Rose"))
           {
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, roseinformation.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
           else {
             // check rest condition using else if ladder.
           }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement button click listener.

I think you are stucking because you don't know how to get a value from `EditText`. So to overcome with it you need to make a `EditText` variable global before `onCreate()` in declaration part.

```
 EditText editText;
```

Now you can initialize it in `onCreate()` method. Now on button click just check

```
 public void onClick(View v)  {
 switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button:
        if (editText.getText().toString().equals("Rose"))
        {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, roseinformation.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
         // do your stuff
        }
        break;
}
}
```